# Enabling X-Content-Type-Options nosniff Makes download request show up on Apple devices using safari

Tags: c#, .net, iphone, safari, x-content-type-options

I am having an issue where when we use an Iphone 13 and newer model in safari a download occurs after the user logs out of the system and this only occurs if we have the below in our web.config:

```
<remove name="X-Content-Type-Options"/>
<add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff" />
```

I have also attached an image of the download that occurs once the user logs out. Is there something we can do to resolve this issue.[image of "do you want to download "LogoutEndpoint"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezcik.png)